# A functional equation involving convolution

Tags: functional-equations, convolution

Let's say I have a smooth function $\varphi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is a convolution kernel.

I am interested in the following equation: $0=A+B~(\varphi*v)+C~v+D~v~(\varphi*v)$, where

- $v:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is the unknown,
- $A, B, C, D$ are four given real constants.

I am interested in existence, uniqueness (and maybe - let's dream - exact formulas for solutions).

I think the problem is not trivial, so I look first for periodic solutions $v$. If any solution exists, then we have the following equations for the Fourier coefficients:

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \quad 0 = A~\delta_0(n) + B~\hat{\varphi}(n)~c_n(v) + C~c_n(v) + D~c_n(v~(\varphi*v))$$

So if I could find a link (an equation) between $c_n(v)$ and $c_n(v~(\varphi*v))$, I could be almost done ! But is it possible ?

Comment: How does that functional equation arise?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Long story short : it is the zeroes of a function of $v$, itself an attempt to model the growth of a population.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen And $v$ is a function of space and time in the original problem. Here we are looking for stationary (in time) solutions $v(x)$.